# How to permanently remove one pst data file from outlook 2003?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, pst

How to permanently remove one pst data file from outlook 2003?

When I try to close the "Pedro Pico.pst" I receive the error message:
"Could not find an object; the operation was not performed."

[image]

[image]

---

I cannot delete this pst file (Pedro Pico.pst) because it is the data file of another profile, which is in use and working at 100%.
It so happens that in this profile this file is loaded automatically, even if you don't intend to.

Answer (score 1):

> How to permanently remove one pst data file from outlook 2003?

Know where the data file is located in Windows Explorer.

Close Outlook.

Delete the PST file manually.

Restart the computer and start Outlook.

Remember that Outlook 2003 is very long gone, out of support, and not fixable in any reliable way.

Also you can start Outlook and Delete the Profile that uses that PST file. That deletes the Account so you need to know how to set up the account again.

Screen Shot of Outlook 2003

[image: Outlook 2003 settings]